# Преобразование виртуальных адресов в физические

Tags: windows, ассемблер

Если взять exe файл и дезасемблировать его (например через IDA PRO) можно увидеть так называемые виртуальные адресса.Ккаким образом компилятор расставляет эти адресса?

Comment: Знаете такого дядьку - Криса Касперски ? Посмотрите его литературу, там, наверняка, найдете много Вам интересного.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользовательская программа под Windows не имеет доступа к физическим адресам в памяти, только к виртуальным.

Если говорить об инструментах: компилятор никак не расставляет адреса, он создает объектный файл с пустыми полями, куда линкер уже пропишет фактические виртуальные адреса или дельты для переходов.

Традиционно (и, видимо, для совместимости со старыми версиями Windows) базовый виртуальных адрес для экзешников выбирается равным 0x400000, для динамических библиотек - вроде бы 0x1000000. Но загрузчик исполняемых файлов Windows вполне может загрузить как экзешник, так и библиотеку по совершенно по другому адресу. Для исправления фиксированных адресов в исполняемом файле/библиотеке, в них присутствует так называемая "таблица релокаций" (таблица перемещаемых элементов, [relocation table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)#Relocation_table)), в которой указаны места в исполняемом файле, где прописаны абсолютные виртуальные адреса. Такие адреса увеличиваются на разницу между исходным базовым адресом (прописанным в файле) и фактическим базовым адресом (по которому данный файл пытается разместить загрузчик).

Дополнительная информация:

- [Википедия: Виртуальная память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)
- Аблязов P. 3. Программирование на ассемблере на платформе х86-64.

Comment: Подскажите, где можно найти информацию про память..? как туда помещаеться код и данные(не в общем,а конкретно, с подробным описанием) и как это все работает.